# NSDictionary to ordered NSArray

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am on OSX, objective-c not iOS. I have an NSDictionary like that

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary alloc initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                @"valueC", @"key3",
                @"valueA", @"key1",
                @"valueB", @"key2",
                nil];
```

When i call allKeys and allValues of NSDictionary, i get NSArrays. But each time the app runs, the order changes - because NSDictionary is an unordered collection.

What i need is an array that contains all values but ordered after keys, alphabetical, ascending like that:

```
@[@"valueA", @"valueB",@"valueC"]; //--> ordered after their keys key1,key2,key3
```

**EDIT**
Basically i need the opposite of this method:

```
- keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: // -> valuesSortedByKeyUsingComparator:
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: y dont u sort allKeys array as per your requirement ?

Comment: hm... maybe i dont understand you. But i need allValues as array. Sorted after their keys.

Comment: if you sort the allKeys, then you can enumerate the sorted all keys, and get their value!

Comment: May you explain it with an example? - ah wait, i think i got the idea of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the keys alphabetically first:

```
   sortedKeyArray = [[mydict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

and enumerate through this sorted array:

```
[sortedKeyArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    [sortedValueArray addObject:mydict[obj];
}];
```

Now you have the sorted value in sortedValueArray

Comment: You can use `objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:` to get the objects.